# How to access two different databases with different admin databases in MongoDB that are hosted on the same server

Tags: mongodb

I have 2 databases. Suppose first DB is X and second DB is Y. X has its own admin DB and Y has its own admin DB. Both X and Y are hosted on the same server.

I want to pull out data from both the DB's X and Y and use it in a query. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: IF those DB's are in same instance, they can't have different admin DB. Only if you run two different instances of mongodb (different ports) you can have different DBs with different admin DBs.

Comment: What do you mean by "database"? See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/databases-and-collections/

Comment: @gunjan   What's your requirement? You want to just fetch data from DBs X,Y within a single connection or you want to a single query to join both data from DBs X,Y?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the data directly in an aggregation pipeline, but you can read the data from other databases and use variables. For example

```
var remoteDB = Mongo("mongodb://username:password@localhost:27016/admin?authSource=admin").getDB("test")
var docs = remoteDB.collection.find().toArray();

db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         remoteData: {
            $filter: {
               input: docs,
               as: "remote",
               cond: { $eq: ["$_id", "$$remote._id"] }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

would be equivalent to this (pseudo-) $lookup:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $lookup: {
         from: "test.collection@remoteDB",
         localField: "_id",
         foreignField: "_id",
         as: "remoteData"
      }
   }
])
```

A copy could be done like this:

```
var remoteDB = Mongo("mongodb://username:password@localhost:27016/admin?authSource=admin").getDB("test")
var docs = remoteDB.collection.find().toArray();

db.dummy_collection.insertOne({})    
db.dummy_collection.aggregate([
   { $limit: 1 },
   { $project: { data: docs } },
   { $unwind: "$data" },
   { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$data" } },
   { $out: "copied_collection" }
])
```